# Unsatisfied Link Error: Flink

Tags: opencv, unsatisfiedlinkerror, apache-flink

I was trying to run a basic program in java by submitting to the job manager in Flink. I have a native library from open CV. When I try to submit the job I get "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path", however when I run it on eclipse by setting up the flink execution environment I get correct results.
I have followed some solutions from the apache flink support website:https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201604.mbox/%3CCAO0MGUj_h==sw76-TWF6x8fnT_Vdc84mwu=YLejjn=bG-up+MQ@mail.gmail.com%3E and have modified my conf.yaml file accordingly (by pointing env.java.opts: -Djava.library.path="/path of Open CV library", but no luck,
Maybe my question is very basic , but still I am stuck, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: Have you made sure that the OpenCV library is also available on the machine on which the JobManager and the TaskManagers are running?

Comment: Actually I was running it locally, and the library is present there.

Comment: This is solved. There was a problem with the fat jar file created from the IDE. It was not including the reference to the native library. So I used custom fat jar creator to make the available and after that uploaded it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, often people references something like the "Tomcat" solution.  Also, Flink with RocksDB writes the so to a tmp file, but this was also wrong.

If anyone else should pass this way- I wrote a short blog outlining the steps I took.  OP's comment answer seems evident, but only after I also see the solution (when I was working on this, it was non-informative).

Shameless self promo:
https://rawkintrevo.org/2017/08/14/using-jnis-like-opencv-in-flink/